# Как написать правильно "все(?)крымский"?

Tags: орфография

Пожалуйста! Может быть: все Крымский? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Всекрымский, по аналогии со Всероссийским, Всебашкирским.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно?

Слитно и с маленькой (строчной) буквы -- к примеру , в таком предложении:

*Закрытие фестиваля превратилось во всекрымский праздник счастья и любви трудящихся масс.*

Если же "всекрымский" употреблено в названиях исторических эпох и событий, календарных периодов и праздников  -- то с прописной.

См. ПАС https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2/:

> § 179...
>
> Примечание 3. В названиях, обозначаемых порядковым номером съездов,
>   конгрессов, конференций, сессий, фестивалей, конкурсов,
>   слова Международный, Всемирный, Всероссийский и т. п. пишутся с
>   прописной буквы независимо от того, обозначается ли стоящий в начале
>   названия порядковый номер цифрой или словом,
>   напр.: I (Первый) Международный конкурс им. П. И. Чайковского,
>   III (Третий) Всероссийский съезд Советов, VI (Шестой) Всемирный
>   фестиваль молодёжи и студентов.